# RIP Puzzling! (#1)

Tags: story, mystery

*May 28, 2024 - On htttps://puzzling2.exchange.com/*

The workflow of questions is normal, everything is good on this new site; yet let's see what's happening on our father site, the great htttps://puzzling.stackexchange.com?

You looked in there, and to your surprise, I saw *nothing*! There was only a message that said:

> I've had enough of this puzzle business! Get back to work!

Then you went to The Vocal Voice, at htttps://puzzling2.exchange.com/vocalvoice. a moderator was already there, as you had assumed.

Mod: "Hey. What's happened? Trying to create a connect wall puzzle."

You: "Something... terrible. "

Mod: "Your Stack Overflow account got deleted?"

You: "No. I've been grumpy with SO for a bit, though."

Mod: "Well, *I* don't have a SO account. "

You: "The Stack Exchange site on Puzzling doesn't work. "

Mod: "Oh, yes. For a couple of days now we've been trying to fix it. Some hacker killed off Puzzling.SE. I saw he left a message behind:"

> Do worry, for we've broken your Puzzling site. 
> And, after all, do we really need a Puzzling site? 
> Rumble, rumble, you think, but it's never gonna help. 
> Keep an eye, for we will soon remove other sites. 
> Maybe you *could* try to stop us, but you'll never succeed. 
> Of course, you don't need SE anyways. 
> Don't know, and you never know, who we are 
> Excellent job on being our victim.

Mod: Uh, and he also mentioned that he was going to kill: Ask Ubuntu, Blender, Raspberry Pi and Poker and Bitcoin.

You: Oh, can we ever stop that hacker?

Mod: Wait, I think I had another message:

> Check your  OS, a tad bit backwards, sorry.

You: Man, I think I could try.. but I don't know.

Comment: Aside from these issues, let me take a small shot: rot13(gur svefg yrggref bs gur zrffntr fcryy QNEX ZBQR, vf guvf gur svany nafjre -- gb rkcynva fbzrguvat vf "unccrarq"?)

Comment: I downvoted based on the puzzle's quality. 99% of the puzzle's text is irrelevant, and the way the solution is hidden is  completely unoriginal and is basically spot-it-and-you're-done.

Comment: Having seen the answer, I agree with @xnor, I expect the downvotes are now because the puzzle is just simply not good. Its a simple gimmick that has been used over and over on this site. I spotted it within 20 seconds of looking at this post but I assumed there would be more to it as it was too easy, and you made it out as if there was a clever trick, when it was just the first letters. Please stop complaining, this is not a good puzzle, and we don't tolerate people being impolite and then complaining about it.

Comment: @zixuanisbadatPuzzling Come on, it's just a puzzle. The wide majority of your puzzles are well received anyway. Learn from the ones that aren't, to create better and better puzzles :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By @athin in the comments:

> The first letters of each line of the message spells out DARK MODE.

Which I'll interpret it as the answer could be

> Dark mode is allowing the hackers to "kill" the sites, as "dark" can also mean evil, or dark enough for the hackers to do their thing unseen. Someone will have to disable dark mode so that the light will shine on them and they will be found out.

Comment: Oh wow. That was it...