# RIP Puzzling! (#2)

Tags: story, steganography, mystery

Last puzzle: [RIP Puzzling! (#1)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106159/rip-puzzling-1)

So, you turn off dark mode, and things *seem* normal at first, but then you see a message at the bottom in red that looked something like this...

> H*a*ha**a**aha! *W*hat ar**e** you going *t*o do now?

You write it in paper, and you say, "Sure, I'm going to figure out what you're planning!"

But then you realize that something, *something* weird was happening to Stack Overflow. All the questions disappeared, then the answers, then the HNQ, until *everything* disappeared. All that was left was the same message that you saw when you turned off dark mode.

Bad luck then takes over, and your computer freezes. You restart it frantically and went to the site again. Same note. You went to the sites he was going to kill. Same note.

Hints:

> Maybe the bolds and italics?

> `NOPUNCTUATION`

> The message is the key

> Order

Comment: Huh? Seriously? What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The farthest I've gotten is the phrase

> **O RIPS TAGS AT**:
>  In the message [which is the key], the bolded and italicized letters appear with 1,2,3,5,8,... letters behind them, respectively. On the assertion that this is, in fact, the Fibonacci sequence, counting off letters [ignoring punctuation] in the rest of the story yields the above phrase.

The bold and italic letters by themselves don't seem to have any meaning, and I don't see an immediate next step. Perhaps the hacker plans to

> delete all the tags from PSE, except he's *already deleted the puzzles!*

Comment: There's a more obvious next step. Can you find it?

Comment: I've accepted this answer, but it's more simple than that, okay? But, I'm still going to accept.

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

> The hacker plans on victory.

Explanation:

> The bolds and italics in
>  
>  > H*a*ha**a**aha! *W*hat ar**e** you going *t*o do now?
>  
>  spells out [**AWET**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk02u5dKYwQUxVMikeNZZsOCqNjZJ6Q%3A1610037855591&ei=Xzr3X5S3I6mp_QaXy7HoDQ&q=awet+meaning&oq=awet+meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyAggAMggIABAIEAcQHjIICAAQCBAHEB4yBggAEAoQHjIGCAAQChAeMgQIABAeMgQIABAeMgYIABAKEB4yBggAEAUQHjoECAAQR1CCUFiCUGC2VWgAcAZ4AIABgAGIAYABkgEDMC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjU4tOzooruAhWpVN8KHZdlDN0Q4dUDCAw&uact=5).

Comment: Good guess... but @AxiomaticSystem's answer is more in line.